# Angularjs allows data updates only for the first rows

Tags: angularjs

I have a code that displays three rows of information from json using angularjs.

Now I want if any values entered in the form inputs corresponding to that rows to replace the already existing values in the view for that rows.

Eg. In row **1** , I have value **hello sub 1** for subcomment Variable. Now I want if I enter another values say **New sub 1**  in the form inputs on that, it will replace/updates the already existing values in the **angular view ** for that rows.

**The problem with the code above is that it keeps on replacing/updating only the subcomment values of the first row each time a new subcomment is entered. irrespective of the save button that was clicked**

I don't know whether problem is from in the line of code below

```
$scope.posts[index].comment[0].subcomment = subcomment;
```

below is the entire partially working code which keeps updating only the first row no matter which submit button that was clicked

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat='post in posts'>
        <b>Post Title:</b> {{ post.title }}
        <div ng-repeat='comment in post.comment'>
            <br>
            <b>sub comment</b>: {{comment.subcomment}}
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Enter subcomment</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type='text' ng-model='subcomment' placeholder="Enter Value For subcomment and Save.">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save and Replace/Update' ng-click='setResponse4(post.id,1,$index,subcomment,comment.id)'>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type='button' style="display:none" ng-init='getComments1(comment.id,5)'>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr style="width:100%;font-size:10">
    </div>
</body>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);


app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.posts = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "my first title.",
            "comment": [
                {
                    "subcomment": "Hello sub 1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "my second title.",
            "comment": [
                {
                    "subcomment": "Hello sub 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "my third title.",
            "comment": [
                {
                    "subcomment": "Hello sub 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    //initialize an arrays of  comments
    $scope.commenting = [];

    $scope.setResponse4 = function (postid, type, index, subcomment, commentid) {
        var subcomment = subcomment;
        alert(subcomment);
        $scope.posts[index].comment[0].subcomment = subcomment;
    }
});
```

Screenshot is attached
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is you have 2 ng-repeats and $index passes the index of the inner ng-repeat whereas you need the index of the outer ng-repeat if you modify your code to take the index of outer ng-repeat as following, it should solve your issue.

1) First add this ng-init to your outer ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat='post in posts track by $index' ng-init="outerIndex=$index">
```

2) use outerIndex in your save function

```
<input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save and Replace/Update' ng-click='setResponse4(post.id,1,outerIndex,subcomment,comment.id)'>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/HcyfzHbyIyfnuk9ifo0d?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes as the code says, you are accessing only the specific index of the array and setting the 0th element value,

```
$scope.posts[index].comment[0].subcomment = subcomment;
```

in order to set all values you can use angular.forEach

```
angular.forEach($scope.posts[index].comment, function(value, key){
   value.subcomment = subcomment;
}
```

Comment: Sir, Your solution still give the same problem as mine.  You can run the script and see the problem. Try to enter a value in a form input at row 2 or 3 and click on save. Instead of the updates to appear on view  on the corresponding rows for  subcomment at 2 or 3, it will keep appearing on the first row on the view. what about initializing an array for $scope.posts=[]; I have added it but still with no luck

Comment: Is there any futher solution on this.